# Can I install Windows 10 on an old Mac ('13 late 2008)

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot-camp, windows-10-upgrade

As the title says, can I install Windows 10 on my old MacBook? I've checked on Apple's website that my MacBook doesn't support Windows 8 or later because of BootCamp drivers issue.. But, all drivers that worked on Windows 7 should work on Windows 10 right?

Comment: Try it.  Worst thing that will happen is it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use windows 10 on your mac but not with the bootcamp([The following Mac models support 64-bit versions of Windows 10 when installed using Boot Camp and your system isn't their on the list so it sure will arise some issues when using](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204990))although their are another ways you can use windows 10 on your mac.

> - **Virtual Machine**--A virtual machine is one of the best ways to run Windows desktop software. They allow you to install Windows and
>     other operating systems in a window on your Mac desktop. Windows will
>     think it’s running on a real computer, but it’s actually running
>     inside a piece of software on your Mac.
>
> Popular virtual machine programs for Mac include [VMware Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/fusion-evaluation.html?PID=3607085&PubCID=2786910)
>   and **Parallels**. Each of these is a paid program, so you’ll have to
>   buy both a Windows license and a copy of your virtual machine program
>   of choice. You can also use the completely free and open-source
>   **VirtualBox for Mac**, but its 3D graphics support and Mac operating system integration aren’t as good. VMware Fusion and Parallels both
>   offer free trials, so you can try all these programs and decide which
>   is best for you.
>
> - **Wine**--Wine originated on Linux. It’s a compatibility layer that allows Windows applications to run on other operating systems.
>     Essentially, Wine is an attempt to rewrite the Windows code that
>     applications depend on so they can run on other operating systems.
>     This means that Wine is nowhere near perfect. It won’t run every
>     Windows application and will have bugs with many of them. The **Wine
>     AppDB** can give you some idea of which applications are supported,
>     although it focuses on Linux support.
>
> Nevertheless, Wine is one way to try running Windows applications on a
>   Mac. Because it doesn’t require you actually use Windows, you don’t
>   need a Windows license to use Wine. It’s completely free.
>
> - **CrossOver Mac**- CrossOver Mac is a paid application that will run Windows programs on Mac. It uses the open-source Wine code to
>     accomplish this, but CrossOver provides a nice graphical interface and
>     focuses on officially supporting popular programs. If an officially
>     supported program doesn’t work, you can contact CodeWeavers and expect
>     them to make it work for you. CodeWeavers contributes their
>     improvements back to the open-source Wine project, so paying for
>     CrossOver Mac also helps the Wine project itself.
>
> Most people will probably be happiest going for a virtual machine
>   program and a Windows license. With CrossOver, you don’t need to run a
>   Windows virtual machine — but if you do run a Windows virtual machine,
>   you’ll be able to run almost any Windows program with less risk of
>   bugs. CrossOver does theoretically allow you to run Windows PC games
>   on a Mac with better performance than you’d get in a virtual machine,
>   but you’ll risk running into bugs and unsupported programs. Boot Camp
>   may be a better solution here.
>
> - **Remote Desktop**-You could also skip running Windows software on your Mac completely and  **use remote desktop software** to access a
>     remote Windows system running your Windows applications of choice.
>     Organizations with business software that runs on Windows can host
>     Windows servers and make their applications available to Macs,
>     Chromebooks, Linux PCs, iPads, Android tablet, and other devices. If
>     you’re just a home user who also has a Windows PC, you could configure
>     that Windows PC for remote access and connect to it whenever you need
>     a Windows application. Bear in mind that this isn’t ideal for visually
>     intensive applications like PC games.
>
> If you’re a Chrome user, you can even **use Chrome Remote Desktop** to
>   connect to a Windows PC running Chrome from your Mac running Chrome.
>
> **Although all these tricks obviously require more work than simply installing a Windows program on a Windows PC. If you have a Mac, you
>   should focus on using Mac software. Windows programs won’t be as
>   integrated or work as well. You may have to buy a Windows license for
>   your Mac to get the best compatibility, whether you’re using a virtual
>   machine or installing Windows in Boot Camp. Wine and CrossOver are
>   nice ideas, but they aren’t perfect.**
>
> [Here is the link for more details](http://www.howtogeek.com/187359/5-ways-to-run-windows-software-on-a-mac/)

Comment: I tried to install bootcamp on windows 64 bits althought not supported but still managed to get it working. also, my another pc's old drivers are compatible with windows 10 although it is not certified